# SuiteScript Inventory Choice

Tags: suitescript

I am using matrix items with a hierarchy, what would be the best inventory value to use when talking about saleable items? And where would I find it? If I look in locations line item on a child record in SuiteScipt I get 
location:"1"
location_display:"Main"
locationid:"1"
quantityavailable:"0"
quantityavailablebase:"0"

But if I look in the interface in an item in NetSuite I also see "Quantity On Hand" , "Quantity On Hand (base unit)", "Quantity Available" , "Quantity Available (base unit)" others also like "Quantity Committed", "Quantity Back Ordered", "Quantity In Transit" the last group unlikeley but I am including them, also notably the last 3 have no values anyway. If I am to write a script that determines stock conditions for saleable items, which value or values should I use and where are they located. Thanks and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out, apparently, the "On Hand" value is a total that includes the sum of the "Quantity Available" and the "Quantity Committed", the "Quantity Available" should be reflective of the Saleable amount of product. This may also have to summed across multiple locations.

thanks anyone who was looking into this for me